# Django-admin brite force protection and more

Tags: python, django, django-admin, brute-force

I know this is a well covered theme on SO, but can someone tell me is there some third party package on `django-admin` protection which is supproting `django` version 1.8 + and python 3.4+. It seems all I have found is outdated and supporting <1.7 `django` version and python 2.7.

Further more, can someone explain how can I manually protect django-admin, what will be the step's to take when writing a code to protect django-admin against brute-force attacks?

Comment: There are some repository, like [django-defender](https://github.com/jazzband/django-defender) and [django-axes](https://github.com/jazzband/django-axes).

Answer (score 2):

I use two methods:

The authentication backend caching a last login attempt and rejects the too frequents attempts.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.core.cache import cache
import datetime

class BruteForceProtectedAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        last_login = cache.get(username + '-login-attempt', now - datetime.timedelta(days=1))
        cache.set(username + '-login-attempt', now)
        if (now - last_login) < datetime.timedelta(seconds=settings.AUTH_RATE):
            return None

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Middleware rejecting request to admin urls from non local IP addresses.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from django.conf import settings
from ipware.ip import get_ip

class ProtectAdminSiteMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith(reverse('admin:index')):
            remote_addr = get_ip(request)
            if remote_addr is None:
                return HttpResponseForbidden('Forbiden')
            else:
                if not remote_addr in settings.INTERNAL_IPS:
                    return HttpResponseForbidden('Forbiden')
        return None
```

Comment: Do you perhaps know any examples that I can see, first time doing this, so I'm trying to gather as much resources as I can get